# Zend Framework 2 Paginator + TableGateway

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-db, zend-paginator, tablegateway

### How to use the database mapper with the paginator?

I'm having a bit trouble understanding how I implement the DbSelect paginator using the code below (right now it's using the Iterator adapter which doesn't work for ResultSets).

From what I can tell it's not as straight forward as I would have hoped. DbSelect is expecting a `Zend\Db\Sql\Select` and an adapter. The adapter is a non issue and can be retrieved with:

```
$this->newsContents()->getAdapter()
```

but I'm having trouble getting a `Select` object out from my TableGateway without duplicating my query code. Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

**NewsController.php**

```
<?php

namespace News\Controller;

use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;

class NewsController extends \Application\Controller\WebsiteController
{
    protected $newsTable;

    protected $newsContents;

    protected function newsTable()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('News\Model\NewsTable');
    }

    protected function newsContents()
    {
        return $this->getServiceLocator()->get('News\Model\NewsContentsTable');
    }

    protected function articleId()
    {
        return (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
    }

    public function articleAction()
    {
        $article = $this->newsTable()->getArticle($this->articleId());
        $pages   = $this->newsContents()->getPages($this->articleId());

        $paginator = new Paginator(new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator($pages));
        $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page'));

        return array(
            'css'       => 'news.css',
            'article'   => $article,
            'paginator' => $paginator,
        );
    }
}
```

**NewsContentsTable.php**

```
<?php

namespace News\Model;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway;
use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

class NewsContentsTable extends \Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway
{
    protected $table = 'news_contents';

    public function __construct(Adapter $adapter)
    {
        $this->adapter = $adapter;
        $this->resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet;
        $this->resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new NewsContents);
        $this->initialize();
    }

    public function getPages($newsId)
    {
        $rowset = $this->select(function(Select $select) use ($newsId)
        {
            $select
                ->order('order ASC')
                ->where(array('news_id' => $newsId));
        });

        return $rowset;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing paginator with DbSelect as the adapter

```
// controller
public function articleAction()
{
    //...
    $paginator = $this->newsContents()->getPages($this->articleId());
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($this->params()->fromRoute('page'));

    return array(
        'css'       => 'news.css',
        'article'   => $article,
        'paginator' => $paginator,
    );
}
?>

// table
public function getPages($newsId)
{
    $sql = $this->getSql();
    $select = $sql->select();
    $select->where(array('news_id' => $newsId))->order('id ASC');
    $adapter = new \Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect($select, $sql);
    $paginator = new \Zend\Paginator\Paginator($adapter);
    return $paginator;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like it's the most correct out of the ones provided.

Comment: Good answer but, how this paginator works? The class itself will add a limit and an offset to the query based on setCurrentPageNumber() or setItemCountPerPage() ? ....or it just use something like array_slice() ?...i am sure it is smarter that this. Right?

Answer (score 7):

From Zend Framework 2.2 its much easier (and allows you to fully enjoy the advantages offered by the TableGateway) - you should use

```
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbTableGateway;  // !!!

 
$dbTableGatewayAdapter = new DbTableGateway($this->tableGateway);
$paginator = new Paginator($dbTableGatewayAdapter);
return $paginator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **buffer**() and **next()** before return in $rowset.

```
$rowset->buffer();
$rowset->next();

return $rowset;
```

Answer (score 0):

> > but I'm having trouble getting a Select object out from my TableGateway without duplicating my query code. Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

You can get the select object inside you NewsContentsTable class like this:

```
$this->getSql()->select();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code for pagination in ZF2

```
 <?php
    //var/www/html/zend_app/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/Plugin/MyCustomPlugin.php
    namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

    use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;

    use Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
    use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Where;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;

    use Zend\Paginator\Paginator;
    use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as paginatorIterator;
    use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\DbSelect;

    class MyCustomPlugin extends AbstractPlugin {

        protected $adapter;

        public function __construct(\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter $adapter) {
            $this->adapter = $adapter;
        }




         public function getPaginatedTableData($tableName, $whereData = "", $selectedColumn = '' , $currentPageNumber = 1) {

            $sql = new Sql($this->adapter);
            $select = $sql->select();

            if ($selectedColumn) {
                $select->columns($selectedColumn);
            }
            $select->from($tableName);
            if ($whereData) {
                $select->where($whereData);
            }

            $paginator = $this->getPaginatorForSelect($select, $currentPageNumber);


            $resultSet = new ResultSet;
            $resultSet->initialize($paginator);
            $resultSet->buffer();

              $pagination = array(
               'current_page_number'=>$currentPageNumber,
               'page_count'=>$paginator->getPages()->pageCount,
               'previous'=>isset($paginator->getPages()->previous)?$paginator->getPages()->previous:0,
               'next'=>isset($paginator->getPages()->next)?$paginator->getPages()->next:0,
               );


 return ($resultSet &&  0 != $paginator->getPages()->pageCount)?array('resultSet'=>$resultSet->toArray(), 'pagination'=>$pagination):FALSE;

        }




        public function getPaginatorForSelect($select, $page, $limit=2)
    {
    $paginatorAdapter = new DbSelect($select, $this->adapter);
    $paginator = new Paginator($paginatorAdapter);
    $paginator->setItemCountPerPage($limit);
    $paginator->setPageRange(5);
    $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);
    return $paginator;
    }

    }
```

HTH